# How to manipulate the attribute value in xml data and insert into database

Tags: t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

How to manipulate the language attribute value in the following example, say to select EN1.

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = N'<email><account language="English" /></email>'

SELECT T.C.value('@language', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('email/account') T(C)
```

I am thinking something like this

```
SELECT T.C.value(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@language, 1,2), '1'), 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('email/account') T(C)
```

Comment: `CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING` should be **around** the expression using the `value` method , not inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Larnu, the following worked

```
SUBSTRING(SELECT T.C.value('@language', 'nvarchar(100)'), 1,2) + '1'
FROM @xml.nodes('email/account') T(C)
```